# oracle built-in audit tracking of trigger execution

Tags: oracle, audit

i'm trying to track down how a record gets created in a table based upon a user action on a webpage.  it's occurring somewhere between ajax calls to application processes/dynamic actions in Application Express (APEX), after submit pl/sql processes in  the APEX page, packages that are called, and triggers on tables involved (etc).  i didn't write the code and no documentation was created.  i could pull my hair out trying to trace through the code, but it is a royal mess.

i was hoping to turn on oracle's built-in auditing, perform the action and inspect the audit logs to see what happened and in what order.  i'm familiar enough with the code that i could pick-up and investigate from there.

my ideal approach would be to turn on auditing for select, insert, update on all tables in the schema.  also turn on execute auditing for all procedures, packages, and triggers.

i'm running into problems where it seems that oracle's built-in auditing doesn't support triggers.

```
AUDIT EXECUTE ON procedure_name BY ACCESS;
and
AUDIT EXECUTE ON package_name BY ACCESS;
```

seem to work fine.

however

```
AUDIT EXECUTE ON trigger_name BY ACCESS;
```

returns an error that the object does not exist.

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this limitation?  Or does anyone have a better idea for how i can track what is going on?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Triggers are executed each and every time the appropriate DML action is applied on the table. Wouldn't it be redundant with `AUDIT INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` ?

Comment: sometimes we have multiple triggers on tables.  some are only before insert, some are both before insert and update, some have logic that stop execution if a certain set of business rules are not met for the record that is being inserted/updated.  therefore, while you are correct in that it seems easy to know what should fire and when, it isn't really easy to follow in the context of business rules being applied.  being able to see one sequential log of everything that executed and what came right before and after it would be very very helpful!

Comment: What you describe is exactly why I don't like triggers doing business logic ! It is hard to maintain, and hard to follow the logic, very much like a succession of GOTO. Unfortunately, AUDIT granularity might be too coarse: you might need to implement your own instrumentation logic. For instance, an autonomous logging procedure that writes to a log table with a comment and a timestamp. You would need to add a call to this procedure in each trigger though.

Comment: yeah, that's what i was afraid of.  i was hoping that i was overlooking or misunderstanding something.  unfortunately, manually adding logging statements might be the way i have to go.  thanks!